# Using DynamoDB without Cognito API

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am using `DynamoDB` or any AWS stuff for the first time and thus have a very little idea how they work. I have seen the documentation where it's mentioned that to use `DynamoDB`, using `IAM` and `Cognito sync` is better way.

I have a very simple requirement. I have an iOS app in which a user can register and login. The functionality is provided by a third party SDK, but I want to store the user information in the DynamoDB table named as `Users`.

I am not sure if I need `Cognito Sync` or `IAM` for this.
So My question is, is it possible to use DynamoDb in iOS without using these two extra features? If yes, then is it possible to do it with the [AWS mobile SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/) or do I need some other ways such as using RESTful APIs for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you use [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), the service takes care of all the steps necessary to create a unique identifier for your app’s users and retrieve temporary, limited privilege AWS credentials. This means that you can follow security best practices, and use these temporary, limited privilege credentials instead of having to hardcode credentials into your app.

You can still use `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` with `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` in the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS, but we discourage its use in production apps for security concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had asked this question, because I was facing some issue with the IAM way. I found a way to fix the issue by using default IAM role for the cognito identity pool. So I no longer require the AccessKey way. Anyways it's good to know the information.